# Why doesn't setdefault work inside a dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary-comprehension, setdefault

Why does setdefault not increment by 1 for every occurrence in `a` inside a dictionary comprehension, but it does in a loop? What's going on here?

Alternative solutions are great. I'm mostly interested in understanding why this doesn't work.

### A loop with setdefault works

```
a = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3]

b = {}

for x in a:
    b[x] = b.setdefault(x, 0) + 1

b

Out[4]: {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2}
```

### A dictionary comprehension with setdefault doesn't work

```
b = {k: b.setdefault(k, 0) + 1 for k in a}

b

Out[7]: {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}
```

### Update

Thanks for the answers, I wanted to try timing the solutions.

```
def using_get(a):
    b = {}
    for x in a:
        b[x] = b.get(x, 0) + 1
    return b


def using_setdefault(a):
    b = {}
    for x in a:
        b[x] = b.setdefault(x, 0) + 1
    return b


timeit.timeit(lambda: Counter(a), number=1000000)
Out[3]: 15.19974103783569

timeit.timeit(lambda: using_get(a), number=1000000)
Out[4]: 3.1597984457950474

timeit.timeit(lambda: using_setdefault(a), number=1000000)
Out[5]: 3.231248461129759
```

Comment: Because `b` is not defined at the time the comprehension is executed. BTW, have you tried `b = collections.Counter(a)`?

Comment: `dict.setdefault` is an odd way to do this anyway - you'd usually use it with a mutable value, not an immutable one (e.g. `d.setdefault[x, []].append(...)`) . I would have written that `b[x] = b.get(x, 0) + 1`.

Comment: *doesn't work*. Actually this works perfectly. If `b = {}`. initially, you will get a new dictionary (freshly assigned to `b`) with values for all keys for `a` and all values `= 0 + 1`. The original `b` is, however, gone. That's probably not what you expected, though. If `b` wasn't defined before the comprehension, you get `NameError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is *no dictionary yet* inside the dict comprehension. You are building a completely new dictionary, **replacing** whatever `b` was bound to before.

In other words, in your dictionary comprehension, `b.setdefault()` is a totally different dictionary, it has nothing to do with the object being built by the comprehension.

In fact, your dictionary comprehension only works if `b` was bound to an object with a `.setdefault()` method before you run the expression. If `b` is not yet defined, or not bound to an object with such a method, it simply fails with an exception:

```
>>> a = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
>>> b = {k: b.setdefault(k, 0) + 1 for k in a}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
>>> b = 42
>>> b = {k: b.setdefault(k, 0) + 1 for k in a}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

You cannot do what you want with a dictionary comprehension, unless you group your numbers, which requires sorting and [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby); this is *not* an efficient approach (requiring O(NlogN) steps rather than O(N)):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> {k: sum(1 for _ in group) for k, group in groupby(sorted(a))}
{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2}
```

Note that the standard library already comes with a tool to do counting; see the [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(a)
Counter({2: 3, 1: 2, 3: 2})
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your second snippet raises a `NameError` if you try it in a clean namespace (one where there's no prior definition of `b`):

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
>>> a = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
>>> b = {k: b.setdefault(k, 0) + 1 for k in a}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

Which should give you a hint at what went wrong.

The statement:

```
b = {k: b.setdefault(k, 0) + 1 for k in a}
```

*first* evaluates (well, actually tries to...) the right-hand side expression `{k: b.setdefault(k, 0) + 1 for k in a}`, and *then* binds the result to name `b`.

If `b` is not defined when the expression is eval'd, you get the above exception (of course). If it's defined and bound to a dict (or whatever have a  `setdefault(x, y)` method FWIW) you get the result of calling `setdefault()` on whathever `b` is bound to at this point.

Answer (score 2):

This does not work because `b` is not defined before the dictionary comprehension is completed. Normally, you should get a `NameError` for this; if not, then because you already defined `b` before, but this will be a different dictionary.

Having said that: It seems that you can just use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this.

```
>>> a = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
>>> collections.Counter(a)
Counter({2: 3, 1: 2, 3: 2})
```